# Getting rid of weird box VSC

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBixs.png)

How do I disable this setting? I don't even know what to call it.

Found a fix: It's called "parameter hints"
shift+cmd/ctrl+space to disable.

Comment: That's the documentation of that function.. https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/functions.html#print You don't have to look at it if you know the function but that's the one thing I wouldn't turn off but rather learn to understand to read

Comment: for the basic functions it is most of the time not needed but when you write a big python project it helps to view the doc of the stuff you write or your team mates write

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a preference to your `settings.json` to not show it automatically while typing:

```json
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false
```

You can also do it on a per-language basis if instead of to the top level object, you add it under a specific language:

```json
"[python]": {
  "editor.parameterHints.enabled": false
}
```